# jetty: how to modify embedded jetty server start config in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using embedded jetty server in a springboot project. I need to set following configuration.

```
--module=jvm
--exec
-javaagent xxxx.jar
```

The document shows these configuration should set in start.ini. But embedded jetty does not have start.ini. Any idea about how to set start.ini properies in an embedded jetty?

Comment: I doubt that setting those will change anything for the embedded container. The java agent you can set like you always do when using java. `java -javaagent xxxx.jar` that isn't specific to Jetty but rather a general Java thing.

Comment: Acutally, the java agent is a security monitor which should set in the program. I have to run the main of springboot to start it. So I can not use the java -javaagent xxx.jar